# Add widget to a float layout Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

im new in kivy, i am trying to attack a widget to a float layout, i have use a code from an example:

http://kivy.org/docs/guide/firstwidget.html

```
 from random import random
 from kivy.app import App
 from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
 from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
 from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


 class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

      def on_touch_down(self, touch):
         color = (random(), random(), random())

         with self.canvas:
             Color(*color)
             d = 15.

             Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
             touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

     def on_touch_move(self, touch):
         touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

 class KivyDotsLayout(FloatLayout):

     def __init__(self):
         super(KivyDotsLayout, self).__init__()
         self.add_widget(MyPaintWidget)



 class MyPaintApp(App):

def build(self):
    return KivyDotsLayout()


 if __name__ == '__main__':
     MyPaintApp().run()<code>
```

but then he gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/Painkiller/PycharmProjects/Prova/Game/DotsGAme/example.py", line 40, in <module>
     MyPaintApp().run()
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/app.py", line 798, in run
     root = self.build()
   File "/Users/Painkiller/PycharmProjects/Prova/Game/DotsGAme/example.py", line 36, in build
     return KivyDotsLayout()
   File "/Users/Painkiller/PycharmProjects/Prova/Game/DotsGAme/example.py", line 29, in __init__
     self.add_widget(MyPaintWidget)
   File "/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 115, in add_widget
     pos_hint=self._trigger_layout)

 TypeError: descriptor 'bind' of 'kivy._event.EventDispatcher' object needs an argument
```

but there arent bind...please help me

Comment: It looks like you're using a Github library. You should post this in the Issues section of that Github project. Author and other users can help you better

Comment: Posting on stackoverflow is fine. Kivy is a popular library with many users, some of whom regularly answer questions about it here.

Answer (score 2):

> self.add_widget(MyPaintWidget)

This should be `self.add_widget(MyPaintWidget())` - you need an *instance* of the class, not the class declaration itself.